# Combine two images in one canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using this code to display data of two canvas into third canvas but it is not working.
I am saving the two canvas data using localstorage and passing it to third canvas

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//First canvas data
var img1 = loadImage(localStorage.getItem('cbdata'), main);
//Second canvas data
var img2 = loadImage(localStorage.getItem('cbdata1'), main);
var imagesLoaded = 0;

function main() {
    imagesLoaded += 1;
    if (imagesLoaded == 2) {
        // composite now
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
    }
}

function loadImage(src, onload) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = onload;
    img.src = src;
    return img;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? Please give in your question examples of both the desired behavior and the actual behavior.

Comment: Code you have given looks ok. Have you checked the console for any errors? Are you sure there is data in `localStorage["cddata"]` and is that data the correct format?

Comment: yes it shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Comment: The script has to run after the element with the id `canvas` has been created. Move the script block at the end of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works. Check that the content of `localStorage.getItem` is non-empty. And I also slightly modified display of the images by changing `ctx.drawImage` commands:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//First canvas data
var img1 = loadImage('http://ep01.epimg.net/elpais/imagenes/2015/10/21/ciencia/1445444934_907402_1445781076_portada_normal.jpg', main);
//Second canvas data
var img2 = loadImage('http://ep01.epimg.net/economia/imagenes/2015/10/22/actualidad/1445508003_507635_1445508894_portada_normal.jpg', main);

var imagesLoaded = 0;

function main() {
    imagesLoaded += 1;

    if (imagesLoaded == 2) {
        // composite now
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, 100, 100);

        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        ctx.drawImage(img2, 100, 0, 100, 100);
    }
}

function loadImage(src, onload) {
    console.log('loadImage', src);
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = onload;
    img.src = src;

    return img;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4Le4g8ta/